# How am I supposed to unit test a singleton in JavaScript using Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, debugging, singleton, jasmine

I've got some code that looks like this:

```
var x = x || (function() {

    // Some private variables
    // ...

    return {
        init:function(options) {
            // Do stuff
            // ...
        },

        // Some other public methods
        // ...
    };
})();
```

If I'm correct then this is a singleton class. Now I wanted to write some unit tests for this class using Jasmine. I started with something like this:

```
describe("x", function() {

    var myX;

    beforeEach(function(){
        myX = x; 
    });

    it("has been instatiated correctly", function() {
        expect(myX.init).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

I've got the understanding that, since there are parentheses around the outermost `function(){}`, this singleton gets instantiated [immediately after it has been parsed.](http://www.hardcode.nl/subcategory_1/article_526-singleton-examples-in-javascript.htm) The lack of a call to this singleton's `init` method in the rest of the code strengthens my assumption (what is the sense of the `init` method in this case anyway?).

Concluding from this I know that

```
var myX;

beforeEach(function(){
    myX = x; 
});
```

can't be right. I've tried many other permutations to get something to work with (starting from leaving it all out, since I figured that the file containing the code has already been parsed at the point when the browser reaches the test spec, so the singleton class should be available, right?). But everything results in exactly the same error message:

```
ReferenceError: x is not defined
```

So how do I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

– Chris

Comment: "*what is the sense of the init method in this case anyway?*" - **You** should know that, it's your module. We didn't write the code.

Comment: I didn't either. I'm just supposed to write the tests. But thanks (;

Comment: If you get `x is not defined`, you seem not to have included the module code. Please show us how you embed it in your tests. Btw, why don't you just `expect(x.init).toBeDefined()`?

Comment: As I said, I've tried many ways, also not "instantiating" the class. In this case I used `expect(x.init).toBeDefined()` of course. Same error message. I included the source file and the spec file in the `SpecRunner.html` (source first, then spec) using a common `<script>` tag.

Comment: Yes, probably you did not load the module correctly, as `x` *would be defined* otherwise. Show us the code that should load them!

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to get back to you. The code how I load the modules into the `SpecRunner.html` looks like this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/x.js"></script>` and `<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/xSpec.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

> If you get x is not defined, you seem not to have included the module code. Please show us how you embed it in your tests.

Use two type assertions, one before instantiation, and one after instantiation, to test a singleton:

```
function foo()
  {
  foo = {};
  return 1;
  }

console.assert(foo.constructor === Object, "foo.constructor === Function", 'foo should be a type of Function before it is instantiated')

foo();

console.assert(foo.constructor === Object, "foo.constructor === Object", 'foo should be a type of Object after it is instantiated')
```

**References**

- [MOP: Metamodel Oriented Programming](http://www.infoq.com/articles/mop)